# Excel VBA - improve time when comparing rows by color

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I have a list of elements. Each row has a color.
For each color, I create a button which make hide the others rows.

For example, if I click on the button for the red, all rows which are not red are hidden.

And there is a reset button to unhide all the rows
Here the code:

```
Sub Red_Click()
    Dim Color_Index As Long
    Color_Index = Range("I1").Interior.ColorIndex
    Call HideOther(Color_Index)
End Sub

Sub Green_Click()
Dim Color_Index As Long
Color_Index = Range("E1").Interior.ColorIndex
Call HideOther(Color_Index)
End Sub

Sub HideOther(Color_Index)
    Set rRange = Range("$A4:$A313")
    For Each cl In rRange
        currentColIndex = cl.Interior.ColorIndex
        If currentColIndex <> Color_Index Then
            cl.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub

Sub Reset()
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

I compare each row color with my color.

I have 300 rows so it take some times (around 15 seconds), is there a way to improve the time? I ask this because the reset/unhide function is immediate.

I'm a beginner in excel so maybe I don't see easier solutions

Comment: If you have Excel 2007 or later you can autofilter by colour. Recording a macro while doing it will give you the basic code.

Comment: Turning off screen updating at the start might help a bit. Application.ScreenUpdating = False (set back to true at end).

Comment: Also, you may disable events and enable them again, disable automatic recalculation and reenable it etc.

Comment: @Rory : yes, I still don't know all the excel tools, my bad. But it's not always convenient to use them, because of merged cells, of how your data is ordered... so i prefer use macros but yes It's make me miss the easiest ways.

Comment: @MissPalmer: it helps a lot but the answer of Ian Montgomery is what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was said in comments, turning off screen updating will help. Depending on your data, turning off calculation might help too.

Other than that, the major improvement in speed would be hiding all rows at once:

```
Sub HideOther(Color_Index)
    Dim cells As Range

    Set rRange = Range("$A4:$A313")
    For Each cl In rRange
        currentColIndex = cl.Interior.ColorIndex
        If currentColIndex <> Color_Index Then
            If Not cells Is Nothing Then
                Set cells = Union(cells, cl)
            Else
                Set cells = cl
            End If
        End If
    Next cl

    cells.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it will be slightly faster as I'm predefining less stuff and using defined variables (i.e. I don't know what I'm doing).

```
Sub Red_Click()
    Dim Color_Index As Long
    Color_Index = Range("I1").Interior.ColorIndex
    Call HideOther(Color_Index)
End Sub

Sub Green_Click()
Dim Color_Index As Long
Color_Index = Range("E1").Interior.ColorIndex
Call HideOther(Color_Index)
End Sub

Sub HideOther(Color_Index As Long)
    For Each Cell In Range("$A4:$A313")                                               'why define something when you're
        If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> Color_Index Then Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True  'using it but once
    Next
End Sub

Sub Reset()
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```